python-mapnik on ubuntu 22.04 build error
I have built mapnik and now want to build python-mapnik, but an error occurs during the pip process. 'mapnik-config' is present, Mapnik version: 4.0.4.
log：
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp: In function ‘void export_gamma_method()’:
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:39:33: error: ‘GAMMA_POWER’ is not a member of ‘mapnik’; did you mean ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_POWER’?
   39 |         .value("POWER", mapnik::GAMMA_POWER)
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/mapnik/symbolizer_enumerations.hpp:167:5: note: ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_POWER’ declared here
  167 |     GAMMA_POWER,     // agg::gamma_power
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:40:33: error: ‘GAMMA_LINEAR’ is not a member of ‘mapnik’; did you mean ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_LINEAR’?
   40 |         .value("LINEAR",mapnik::GAMMA_LINEAR)
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/mapnik/symbolizer_enumerations.hpp:168:5: note: ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_LINEAR’ declared here
  168 |     GAMMA_LINEAR,    // agg::gamma_linear
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:41:32: error: ‘GAMMA_NONE’ is not a member of ‘mapnik’; did you mean ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_NONE’?
   41 |         .value("NONE", mapnik::GAMMA_NONE)
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/mapnik/symbolizer_enumerations.hpp:169:5: note: ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_NONE’ declared here
  169 |     GAMMA_NONE,      // agg::gamma_none
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:42:37: error: ‘GAMMA_THRESHOLD’ is not a member of ‘mapnik’; did you mean ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_THRESHOLD’?
   42 |         .value("THRESHOLD", mapnik::GAMMA_THRESHOLD)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/mapnik/symbolizer_enumerations.hpp:170:5: note: ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_THRESHOLD’ declared here
  170 |     GAMMA_THRESHOLD, // agg::gamma_threshold
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:43:36: error: ‘GAMMA_MULTIPLY’ is not a member of ‘mapnik’; did you mean ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_MULTIPLY’?
   43 |         .value("MULTIPLY", mapnik::GAMMA_MULTIPLY)
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/mapnik/symbolizer_enumerations.hpp:171:5: note: ‘mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_MULTIPLY’ declared here
  171 |     GAMMA_MULTIPLY,  // agg::gamma_multiply
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:32:
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void mapnik::enumeration_<EnumWrapper>::init() [with EnumWrapper = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>]’:
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp:51:9:   required from ‘mapnik::enumeration_<EnumWrapper>::enumeration_(const char*) [with EnumWrapper = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>]’
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:38:64:   required from here
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp:80:47: error: ‘MAX’ is not a member of ‘mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>’
   80 |         for (unsigned i = 0; i < EnumWrapper::MAX; ++i)
      |                                               ^~~
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp:83:54: error: ‘get_string’ is not a member of ‘mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>’
   83 |             base_type::value( EnumWrapper::get_string( i ), native_type( i ) );
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static PyObject* mapnik::enumeration_<EnumWrapper>::converter::convert(const EnumWrapper&) [with EnumWrapper = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/python/converter/as_to_python_function.hpp:27:61:   required from ‘static PyObject* boost::python::converter::as_to_python_function<T, ToPython>::convert(const void*) [with T = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>; ToPython = mapnik::enumeration_<mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup> >::converter; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/local/include/boost/python/to_python_converter.hpp:83:9:   required from ‘boost::python::to_python_converter<T, Conversion, has_get_pytype>::to_python_converter() [with T = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>; Conversion = mapnik::enumeration_<mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup> >::converter; bool has_get_pytype = false]’
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp:78:24:   required from ‘void mapnik::enumeration_<EnumWrapper>::init() [with EnumWrapper = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>]’
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp:51:9:   required from ‘mapnik::enumeration_<EnumWrapper>::enumeration_(const char*) [with EnumWrapper = mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>]’
src/mapnik_gamma_method.cpp:38:64:   required from here
src/mapnik_enumeration.hpp:71:20: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘const mapnik::enumeration<mapnik::gamma_method_enum, mapnik::gamma_method_e_to_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_from_string, mapnik::gamma_method_e_lookup>’ to type ‘long int’
   71 |                 ,  static_cast<long>( v ));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command '/usr/bin/c++' failed with exit code 1


I tried fixing the references to the GAMMA_* constants, replacing mapnik::GAMMA_* in the code with mapnik::gamma_method_enum::GAMMA_*. How to solve other errors? Please advise
